# How can i install facebook lite on my desktop without first logging into the original facebook application?

Tags: facebook

Currently using Ubuntu version 20.04. Facebook has locked me out of my original account. But I can use facebook lite on my cell phone, am wondering if I can install fb lite without using original fb log in onto my desktop comouter?